# how to change a listview item font color

Tags: android, listview

Is there a simple way to change the font color of a specific listview item?  I have an ArrayAdapter item that I pass to setAdapter() in ListView.  I just want to change the color of a specific element in the list.

this is my code so far

```
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Please post your code. So its easy to help!

Answer (score 0):

In your listview.xml, you need to do it at your element (in this case it's a textview):

```
<TextView
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
```

In the folder *values*, you need to create a colors.xml file. Into the file you put:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

It's a html color

I hope I have helped you

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter's code

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
   MyView view;
   if( convertView == null )
   {
       // Get the item to draw
       Item i = getItem( position );

       // Create its view
       view = new MyView( ... );

       if( i.isSpecific )
       {
           // If its your specific item change the bg color 
           view.setBackground( color );
       }
   }
   else
   {
       // Don't create a view if it's already exist
       view = convertView;
   }
return view;
```

}

Comment: so I have to create an Adapter class that extends ArrayAdapter?

Comment: Yes exactly and override the getView method.

Comment: so when I create a new View, what context do i send to the constructor?